# Как использовать logger.info(из log4j) в консоли вместо print?

Tags: java, логирование, log4j

Надо выводить какие-то действия в консоль + логировать их в файл. 
Я сделал это с помощью log4j. У меня для вывода в файл + консоль используется `ApplicationLogger.logger.info("...");`, но после каждого вывода в консоль он делает перенос строки. Простым языком, он выводит как `println`, а мне нужно что-бы выводил в консоль как `print`.

Файл `log4j.properties`:

```
#
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
#
log4j.appender.file.File=./checkers.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.append=false
#
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Класс `ApplicationLogger`:

```
public class ApplicationLogger {
    public final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ApplicationLogger.class);
}
```

Может нужно поменять `PatternLayout` на другой?

Comment: `%n` уберите из формата

Comment: @AntonShchyrov т.е. log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern= %m
Вроде тоже не то

Comment: Почему, вдруг, не то?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov простите, перепутал, все правильно)). Почему бы вам не оформить как ответ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как написал [Anton Shchyrov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/221228/anton-shchyrov), нужно убрать `%n` из `layout`. `ConversionPattern` должен стать таким:

```
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%m
```